# passing data from async callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

for some reasons I need to passing data from async callback,

it's not a big deal if the target is a global variable,

but the variable just using in a method, so I hope I can do it in a method.

```
- (void)login
{
    dispatch_group_t login_group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSString* secureToken = nil;
    NSString* loginSeed = nil;

    [self getSecureToken:&secureToken group:login_group];
    [self getLoginSeed:&loginSeed group:login_group];

    dispatch_group_notify(login_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"token: %@", secureToken);
    });
}

- (void)getSecureToken:(NSString **)token group:(dispatch_group_t)group
{
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [_manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
    [_manager GET:@"/secure_token" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //get secure token
        NSDictionary* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        *token = [result objectForKey:@"SECURE_TOKEN"];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
}
```

if I do in this way, then it will print ***null***

anyway I can access data from async callback but not by global variable or delegate ?

cause I just need this data for login method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to have a JavaScript background, you may be familiar with *promises*.

In Objective-C there are a few libraries which implement promises. An approach utilizing a promise library may look something likes this:

Your `login` will become asynchronous (inevitable):

```
- (Promise*)promiseLogin {
    return [self promiseSecureToken]
    .then(^id(NSString* secureToken){
        return [self promiseLoginWithToken:secureToken seed:seed];    
    }, nil);
}
```

Your method `promiseSecureToken` can be implemented as follows:

```
- (Promise*) promiseSecureToken
{
    Promise* promise = [[Promise alloc] init];
    [_manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
    [_manager GET:@"/secure_token" parameters:nil 
                                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
    {
        //get secure token
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* result = 
           [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                             error:&error];
        if (result) {
            NSString* token = [result objectForKey:@"SECURE_TOKEN"];
            [promise fulfillWithValue:token];
        }
        else {
            [promise rejectWithReason:error];
        }
    } 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [promise rejectWithReason:error];
    }];

    return promise;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
[self promiseLogin]
.then(^id(id result){
    // "result" is whatever promiseLoginWithToken:seed: returns
    return something;
},nil)
.then(nil, ^id(NSError*error){
    // catch ANY error, no matter where it occurred in the previous tasks:
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    return nil;
});
```

For a list of libraries and a few more useful information, take a look here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184597/success-failure-blocks-vs-completion-block/219929#219929

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class variable like this and use it anywhere inside your class:

Like:

```
@interface MyViewController()
{
    NSString *token;
}

@end

@implementation MyViewController()

...
```

Otherwise, you could also try to use a completion block for your getSecureToken method?

Like this:

```
- (void)getSecureToken:(NSString **)token group:(dispatch_group_t)group onComplete:(void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success onFail:(void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))fail
{
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    [_manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
    [_manager GET:@"/secure_token" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //get secure token
        NSDictionary* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        *token = [result objectForKey:@"SECURE_TOKEN"];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);



        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        // Check completion block param exists before executing it
        // ---------------------------------------------------------
        if(success)
        {
            success(operation, result);
        }




    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_group_leave(group);

        if(fail)
        {
            fail(operation, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Then you can go:

```
- (void)login
{
    dispatch_group_t login_group = dispatch_group_create();

    NSString* secureToken = nil;
    NSString* loginSeed = nil;

    [self getSecureToken:&secureToken group:login_group onSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

        NSLog(@"token is = %@", [responseObj valueForKey:@"token"]);        

    } onFail:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get token?");
    }];

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice async control flow library [Sequencer](https://github.com/berzniz/Sequencer),
I like this solution, just like async in Node.js :)